# Compute ln addition and subtraction?

Tags: functions, logarithms

I have this function:

$ \phi (x,y) = 2ln(x+y)-ln(x)-ln(y) $

Now I would like to compute $ \phi(\frac{5}{6},1) - \phi(\frac{1}{6},1) $.

I tried it, but can't find my way forward to simplify the expression. It becomes a long, long line of ln-terms. How should I do?

Comment: "long, long line" = 6 terms in total, which you can then expand slightly by using $\ln\left(a/b\right) = \ln a - \ln b$, and then (I hope, or else the problem is stupid) play memory with the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Combining the terms**

We have $$\phi (x,y) = 2\ln(x+y)-\ln(x)-\ln(y)=2\ln(x+y)-\ln(xy)=\ln\left(\frac{(x+y)^2}{xy}\right)$$ So $$\phi\left(\frac56, 1\right)=\ln\left(\frac{\left(\frac56+1\right)^2}{\frac56\cdot1}\right)=\ln\frac{121}{30}$$ and $$\phi\left(\frac16, 1\right)=\ln\left(\frac{\left(\frac16+1\right)^2}{\frac16\cdot1}\right)=\ln\frac{49}{6}$$ Hence $$\phi\left(\frac56, 1\right)-\phi\left(\frac16, 1\right)=\ln\frac{121}{30}-\ln\frac{49}{6}=\color{blue}{\ln\frac{121}{245}}$$

Comment: How does $ ln(x)$ − $ln(y)$ become $ln(xy) $ and not $ln (\frac{x}{y})$ ?

Comment: Micor its $-\ln(x)-\ln(y)=-\ln(xy)$

Comment: So the negative ln(x) makes it ln(xy) rather than ln(x/y)?

Comment: $ln(\frac x y)=ln(x)-ln(y)$....they are both negative in the first example ..

Comment: $\ln BIGTHING - \ln x - \ln y = \ln \frac {BIGTHING}x - \ln y=  \ln \frac {\frac {BIGHTHING}x}y = \ln \frac {BIGTHING}{xy}$.

Comment: Also $-\ln x = (-1)\ln x = \ln x^{-1} = \ln \frac 1x$ so $-\ln x - \ln y = \ln \frac 1x + \ln \frac 1y = \ln \frac 1x\frac 1y = \ln \frac 1{xy}$.   OR FINALLY $-\ln x - \ln y = 0 - \ln x - \ln y = \ln 1 - \ln x - \ln y = \ln \frac 1{xy}$.

Comment: The thing to notice is the equation is $-\ln x - \ln y$ and is not $\ln x - \ln y$  (which would be $\ln \frac xy$.

Answer (score 1):

Use this property: $\ln(a) - \ln(b) = \ln(\frac{a}{b})$. Earlier, I used $x$ and $y$; the variables in this identity are not related to the variables used in the problem.

Check out some more [Properties of Logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities), they might be helpful to you in your math journey.

Comment: I can see it being used in the final step in the simplification made my the other poster, however not in the middle step. Can you explain that?

Comment: Having folks calculate stuff for you is nice and all, but I would recommend you familiarize yourself with the properties of logarithms. Especially, focus on how they relate to exponents. This will help you on your test. Take a gander at the page I linked and try it out for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Identities go both ways.

If $\ln k^n = n \ln k$ and $\ln mj = \ln m + \ln j$, doesn't it make sense that $n\ln k  = \ln k^m$ and $\ln m + \ln j = \ln mj$?

So $\phi (x,y) = 2\ln(x+y)-\ln(x)-\ln(y) = \ln \frac {(x+y)^2}{xy}$

And $\phi(x,y) - \phi(u,v) = \ln \frac {(x+y)^2}{xy} - \ln \frac {(u+v)^2}{uv} = \ln \frac {(x+y)^2uv}{(u+v)^2xy}$.

$\phi(\frac{5}{6},1) - \phi(\frac{1}{6},1) = \ln \frac {(\frac 56+1)^2\frac 16}{(\frac 16 + 1)^2\frac 56}$

[Or directly:

$\phi(\frac{5}{6},1) - \phi(\frac{5}{6},1) =2\ln (\frac 56 + 1) -\ln \frac 56 - \ln 1 - 2\ln(\frac 16 + 1) + \ln \frac 56 + \ln 1 = 2\ln (\frac 56 + 1) -\ln \frac 56 - 2\ln(\frac 16 + 1) + \ln \frac 56 =\ln \frac {(\frac 56 + 1)^2\frac 16}{(\frac 16+1)^2 \frac 56}$

]

And

$\ln \frac {(\frac 56+1)^2\frac 16}{(\frac 16 + 1)^2\frac 56} =\ln \frac {(\frac 56 + 1)^2}{(\frac 16 + 1)^2*5} = \ln \frac {(5+ 6)^2}{(1+6)^2*5} = \ln \frac {121}{245}$.

Answer (score 0):

Or, just plug them in, knowing that $\ln 1=0$: $$\phi\left(\frac56,1\right)=2\ln\left(\frac56+1\right)-\ln\left(\frac56\right)-\ln1=2\ln\frac{11}6-\ln\frac56$$ and $$\phi\left(\frac16,1\right)=2\ln\left(\frac16+1\right)-\ln\left(\frac16\right)-\ln1=2\ln\frac{7}6-\ln\frac16$$ Hence $$\phi\left(\frac56,1\right)-\phi\left(\frac16,1\right)=2\left(\ln\frac{11}6-\ln\frac76\right)-\left(\ln\frac56-\ln\frac16\right)=2\ln\frac{11}7-\ln5$$ which is $$\ln\frac{121}{49}-\ln5=\color{blue}{\ln\frac{121}{245}}$$